# Nginx proxypass по условию

Tags: nginx

Есть несколько списков юзергагентов, и нужно перенапрвлять на разные сервера в зависимости от юзерагента, как это реализовать?

Сделал такое для отключения не нужных

```
map $http_user_agent $bots {
default 0;
~*aBot 1;
~*bBot 1;
}
if ($bots) { return 444; break;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так:

```
upstream backend_a {
  server server_a;
}

upstream backend_b {
  server server_b;
}

upstream backend_c {
  server server_c;
}

map $http_user_agent $backend {
  default backend_a;
  ~aBot   backend_b;
  ~bBot   backend_c;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://$backend;
  }
}
```